# C# to create formatted xml

Tags: c#, xml, format

I am trying to use c# to format my xml to look sth like this.

```
<House>
   United States
   <Home>
      NewYork
      Lagos
      California
   </Home>
</House>
```

Is there any way I can force the indentations? It doesn't indent the any tag that does not have a child element and it does some thing like this:

```
<House>
   United States
   <Home>NewYork Lagos California </Home>
</House>
```

OR

```
<House>United States </House?
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to put newline constants into your values. As far as the xml is concerned, "NewYork 
Lagos 
California" is one value

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the xml format to have all content bounded within an element, you can use the following code. I'll paste the output below the code; notice it will not format your xml string.

```
var dodgyXmlString = "<House>United States<Home>NewYork Lagos California</Home></House>";
var validXmlString = "<House><Place>United States</Place><Home>NewYork</Home><Home>Lagos</Home><Home>California</Home></House>";
var strings = new string[] { dodgyXmlString, validXmlString };

foreach(var xmlString in strings)
{    
    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString);
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    var writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
    xmlDocument.WriteTo(writer);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
}
```

And the output:

```
<House>United States<Home>NewYork Lagos California</Home></House>
<House>
  <Place>United States</Place>
  <Home>NewYork</Home>
  <Home>Lagos</Home>
  <Home>California</Home>
</House>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you can not do that or you're okay with iterating you can do this :

("raw" contains your markup)

```
string[] spliiter = raw.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n' });
List<string> splitterList = spliiter.ToList<string>(), xml = new List<string>();
splitterList.RemoveAll(x => x == "");
string temp;
for (int i = 0; i < splitterList.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    temp = "";
    if (StringExtensions.ContainsAll(splitterList[i], new string[] { "<", ">" }))
    {
        temp = splitterList[i];
        xml.Add(temp);
    }
    else if (!splitterList[i].EndsWith("\r"))
    {
        if (StringExtensions.ContainsNone(splitterList[i], new string[] { "<", ">" }))
        {
            if (splitterList[i + 1].EndsWith("\r") || splitterList[i + 1].EndsWith("\r\n"))
            {
                 temp = splitterList[i] + " " + splitterList[i + 1];
                 xml.Add(temp);
                 i++;
             }
        }
    }
    else if (splitterList[i].EndsWith("\r") && StringExtensions.ContainsNone(splitterList[i], new string[] { "<", ">" }))
    {
        if (splitterList[i + 1].EndsWith("\r") && StringExtensions.ContainsNone(splitterList[i + 1], new string[] { "<", ">" }))
        {
            temp = splitterList[i];
            do
            {
                temp = temp + " " + splitterList[i + 1];
                i++;
             } while (splitterList[i + 1].EndsWith("\r") && StringExtensions.ContainsNone(splitterList[i + 1], new string[] { "<", ">" }) || StringExtensions.ContainsNone(splitterList[i + 1], new string[] { "<", ">", "\r", "\n" }));
             temp.Replace('\n', ' ');
             xml.Add(temp);
         }
         else
         {
             temp = splitterList[i];
             xml.Add(temp);
         }
     }
 }
 xml = (xml.Select(s => (s.Replace('\r', ' ').Trim()))).ToList();
 string final_xml = string.Join("\n", xml.ToArray());
```